# How to fix tabs and space inconsistencies on WingIDE for python 3?

Tags: python

I am having issues with this code, its not any actual code itself, but it's the spacing that causing me an issue. This file came like this, and when I run it, it says "**inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (2, line 11)**" So right after def is_less_than. I have no clue what this means, and know how to fix it, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    class Student():
    def __init__(self, id, name, mark):
        '''Initialize the object properties'''
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.mark = mark

    def __str__(self):
        '''Informal string representation of Student'''
        return ' - {}, {}, {}'.format(self.id, self.name, self.mark)

    def is_less_than(self, another_student):
    ''' 
    Checks if the mark of the student is less than the mark of another 
    Student object
    Input: another_student (Student)
        Returns: boolean
    '''
        # TODO - remove the pass and complete the function
        pass

    def recursive_merge_sort(data):  
        '''
        Uses MergeSort to sort the list of data in INCREASING order
        Returns: the sorted list of Students  
        '''
        # TODO - remove the pass and complete the function
        # Hint: modify your merge sort from exercise 1
        pass
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You seem to have a mixture of spaces and tabs in the comment of `def is_less_than`